# Getting exception on inserting value into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using a code-first approach and I am getting the below exception:

> "Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'CustomerInfo' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for code first configuration."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary key must be unique as it is the one to uniquely identify a row (table entry). What you are possibly doing is trying to set a value for the primary key that is already set fro another table entry. 
One approach to get rid of such problems is to use a primary key that is auto incremented so that you do not need to worry about it. For example you can introduce an additional field as follows to server as the primary key:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Int32 Id { get; set; }
```

Thus this will automatically generate and set a primary key, freeing you from the need to set up the primary key yourself. *Still this is one way to solve your problem and other ways can also be used to solve your problem.*

Comment: This does not solve my problem. Do you have any alternative solution for this?? @Tayyab

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are facing @xyzWty? Please share some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys are unique across the table. So if you give same value for primary key for two or more records, it will fail. Solution is yo sey primary key value as unique.